# How can I programmatically/dynamically create data pipelines that include workers using Kafka and Java?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, rss-reader

On a very high level, I will be providing a multi-tenant platform interface to allow users create "Projects" - translated to Kafka topics for a variety of producer types - RSS feeds, SQL Server queries and file locations.

To retreive RSS data, for example, I believe we will need to create Kafka works to fetch RSS data on a schedule - thus needing to add new multi-threaded workers (or jobs to a worker) dynamically - not through configuration files.

The application abstraction layer will separate the user from Kafka and ElasticSearch. I can't be allowing all users access through Control Center.

In another use case where I may offer some type of managed services, I could use CC.

Given this use I would like to get some details about the appropriate way to accomplish this - as there still seem to be some gaps - i.e. we can't use configuration files as the topics need to be created dynamically.

How can I programmatically/dynamically create data pipelines and workers using Kafka and Java?

Comment: For Java, look at the Pipe class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Pipe.html

Comment: I believe you are addressing the comms to/from producers/consumers  in Kafka?  That doesn't answer the main question.

Comment: Have you looked at the REST API of Kafka Connect (http://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/userguide.html#rest-interface), which you can use to e.g. create new connectors.  That's one option to "dynamically create new workers to fetch RSS data".